# get an access token using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi i am using the following code to get access token from facebook using C# SDK

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = "clientId",
        client_secret = "clientSecret",
        redirect_uri = "redirectUri",
        code = "code"
    });

    return result.access_token;
```

the above code works perfect most of the time but some times i gets this error

```
(OAuthException - #100) Invalid verification code format.
```

how to fix this problem??

Answer (score 4):

What is your project type : **WinForms** , **WPF** , **ASP.NET** ?

if you are working with **WinForms** or **WPF** , you have to get the `access_token` form the `Browser Control` URL by requesting the OAuth Login Dialog and the `return_type=token` , then extract the valid `access_token` from the URL.

Otherwise , if you are working on Web Application using **ASP.NET** , you will have to redirect the user to the OAuth Dialog Login Page then the facebook will redirect you back with a code on the URL , you get this code from the `QueryString` and make an `HTTPRequest` to the Facebook to get the valid `access_token` .

you can use my method for doing that :

```
 public string GetAccessTokenFromCode(string AppID, string AppSecret, string RedirectURL, string Code)
{
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string u2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + AppID + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectURL + "&client_secret=" + AppSecret + "&code=" + Code + "&state=anytexthere";
string access = wc.DownloadString(u2);
access = access.Substring(access.IndexOf("access_token") + 13);
if (access.Contains("&"))
{
string accesstoken = access.Substring(0, access.IndexOf("&"));
return accesstoken;
}

return access;

}
```

and you can call it from the `Page_Load` :

```
if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
{
code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
string AT = GetAccessTokenFromCode(AppID, AppSecret, RedirectUrl, Code);
}
```

Comment: How get the AppId, AppSecret, and Code values ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same `redirect_uri` as you did when asking for `code`.
Also there must be a trailing slash '/' at the end of the site url you configured in 'Website with Facebook Login' section on Facebook.
Here's a complete tutorial: [Working with C# SDK](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html)

Comment: please be more elaborate on when this exception occurs. Try using `Post` request instead of `Get`.

Comment: well i dont know i have it on my website and get lods of techmails out for this error. When i test it or ask my friends to test the links out every thing works fine for me but the tech mails keep coming from some visitors

Comment: can you post the method through which you receive the value for `code`

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) makes me wonder if your code should look more like this:

```
   dynamic result = fbClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = fbClient.AppId,
            client_secret = fbClient.AppSecret,
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = accessToken
        });
```

Maybe your accessToken is timing out or something?

Answer (score -1):

after downloading sdk from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook.CSharp.SDK/

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
//your application id and secret from https://developers.facebook.com/apps
config.Add("appId", "3955.......");
config.Add("secret", "4c1d...............");
config.Add("fileUpload", true); //optional
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(config);
ulong facebookId = client.getUser(); //retrieve user id. if user is not added the app this value is 0
client.getAccessToken()
```

gives you the access token.