# (OAuthException - #190) Malformed access token exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to check in the customer to our cafe on Facebook using our portal on local WiFi network (the site permanently runs on local network). I am using following code that uses Facebook C# SDK:

```
if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null && Request.QueryString["code"] != "")
{
    string AccessToken = Request["code"].ToString();
    var fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = "This is just a test.";
    parameters.place = "<MY PAGE ID>";
    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
    var id = result.id;
}
else
{
    var redirectUri = "http://<LOCAL SERVER IP ADDRESS>:<LOCAL SERVER PORT NUMBER>/FBLogin.aspx";

    var service = new FacebookClient();
    var loginUrl = service.GetLoginUrl(new
    {
        client_id = appID,
        client_secret = appSecret,
        redirect_uri = redirectUri,
        response_type = "code",
        scope = "publish_actions" // Add other permissions as needed
    });

    Response.Redirect(loginUrl.ToString());

    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = appID,
        client_secret = appSecret,
        redirect_uri = redirectUri
        //code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString()
    });
}
```

I tried everything from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887483/malformed-access-token-190-error) and others but I forgot the links, and nothing has worked.

**UPDATE**

I am able to check in using the access token generated directly using Facebook Debug Tool.

Full Exception:

> (OAuthException - #190) Malformed access token
>   AQBQAhmVl6xEYtUmSUzBCdcMq8Djzi-XgEkkFLVwUgT_v592CkhBxOiJ7xX6-PoUpvk2XRqZZ9TahXw8u7_R1qletojvnMR5ENlVTON5tzOg-6b6Mw2foGRyXUEnzNzYhc1p7bb48E9nV5NuB1tg0cFsSM2WSeSTYXnjyyuuuyxEjeqfXy1Kn0PTnIaH1s_2wuKuUCq2AdD-PyHkbj_zUADDnwZCeJk5KSHkqbcKTLgYaIk6roMWJb8xHsExJK86xbRt5jXvS2-bBLwi5dYHn_Fpc7NZjilRvNYWa2gyKSo8ElABnF3Qr051VJInVoNsXiOYTQK24tWvEqvOY_ZeKoId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 'code' to generate AccessToken by:

```
client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<YOUR_URL>&
client_secret=<YOUR_APP_SECRET>&code=<YOUR_CODE>
```

in response you can get the AccessToken.

You can use this code to get accessToken:

```
public String GetAccessToken(string code)
{
    //create the constructor with post type and few data
    MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token", "GET", "client_id=" + this.ApplicationID + "&client_secret=" + this.ApplicationSecret + "&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:5176%2F");

    string accessToken = myRequest.GetResponse().Split('&')[0];
    accessToken = accessToken.Split('=')[1];

    return accessToken;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was confused about. What is code? And where to get it?

Comment: @Aishwarya Shiva read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906486/how-to-get-an-access-token-using-c-sharp-sdk for more information

Comment: or read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975477/get-an-access-token-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk for more information

Comment: I've been through this scenario before, this should be the answer.

Comment: @Abd How to define `MyWebRequest`?